# в заданной строке из цифр и букв, вывести только строчные буквы

Tags: python

Дана строка символов. Вывести на экран только строчные буквы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = 'aBc1dE5fgh'
print(''.join(c for c in s if c.islower() and not c.isdigit()))
```

или

```
s = 'aBc1dE5fgh'
print(''.join(filter(str.islower, filter(str.isalpha, s))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного упрощённый вариант того, что предложил Sergey Gornostaev:

```
s = 'aBc1dE5fgh ?_*'
print(filter(str.islower, s))
```

filter может вернуть строку во втором Питоне, в третьем надо всё же так:

```
print(''.join(filter(str.islower, s)))
```

str.islower() уже отсекает цифры и прочие символы, у которых нет регистра

Answer (score 0):

Вот простой работающий код:

```
x = 'x2Z4AA256'
chisl = ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
res = ""
for y in x:
    if (y == y.lower()) and (y not in chisl):
        res += y
print(res)
```